# JAAS configuration on TomEE

Tags: jakarta-ee, jaas, apache-tomee

I am implementing example

[See here](http://www.simtay.com/simple-crud-web-application-with-jsf-2-1-primefaces-3-5-maven-and-jpa/)

and I am trying to manage to work the login interface.
Actually I am configuring TomEE to use JAAS auth technology.
The author suggested me to read ([See Docs](http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-jaas.html)) to confiture JAAS on TomEE.
The first hint says

```
Add to your CATALINA_OPTS the java.security.auth.login.config system property:
    Djava.security.auth.login.config=$CATALINA_BASE/conf/login.config
```

But I don't know where `java.security.auth.login.config` is. And I do not have any `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/login.config` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Openejb/TomEE mailing list, I understood that you have to:

- Add the  tag to the server.xml;
- create the login.config in TomEE's conf directory;
- add the -Djava parameter to the startup line;
- create the files user.properties and groups.properties in the 
  same directory as the login.config file.